# Can't handle Push Notification when the app is running in Background, receives push but didn't click on the banner or alert

Tags: ios, notifications, push

I have implemented push notification in my application. I have tested the push message in my iPod. The result is as follows:

Scenario Tested:
1. Application Running in Front End, iPod not locked - [status = no problem ]

1. Application Running in Front End, iPod locked - [status =  no problem ]
2. Application Running in Background, iPod not locked - [status = FOUND PROBLEM] not saved in database + no alert (actually not getting any event handler)
3. Application Running in Background, iPod locked - status = no problem if I open the app immediately, but if I wait for 2 mins, then open my app I don't get the message!
4. Application isn't Running (not in Background + Front End), iPod not locked - (FOUND PROBLEM) not saved in database + no alert {I can see push message as an alert, but I don't click it, my app then contain a badge icon, but if I click on my app, I don't get any information of my push message}
5. Application isn't Running(not in Background + Front End), iPod locked - no problem if I unlock the phone immediately, but If I wait for 2 mins, I lost the message!

### ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

If I summarize my problem: I am getting the push notification for all scenario, but I can't handle the notification for some scenario if I don't click on the alert/banner! I want to save the messages in my local database in all scenario for special purposes.

I have seen so many links in stackoverflow and other sites as well, but I didn't see the same scenario that someone already faced!

My iPods iOS version is: 5.0

Can anyone help me regarding this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure how better to put this but: that is how it's supposed to work.

You can't rely on the push notification being the *only* communication mechanism. When your app starts you need to have a way of querying for the current state from your webservice.

The data in the payload of the notification can be used as a shortcut or optimisation but not an *alternative* to a refresh mechanism.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. May be you are suggesting about to use web services rather than push notification. But I believed that there is a solution for my current problem. I looked at more than 50 links, but didn't get a solution! For now I don't want to change the communication mechanism, I will wait for a solution, but if there is no solution, then must think about other communication mechanism. Thanks.

Comment: You don't say where the data comes from, so I assumed a web service. My answer still stands, though. Whatever mechanism you use, you can't rely on push notification as the only way of sending the data.

Comment: I am receiving data from Apple Push Notification Service. My problem is in handling the push notification, I have no receiving problem. Suppose I run my application in debug mode, then I locked my device, in that mean time I received a push notification. I wait for 2-3 minutes, then I unlocked the device. In that case I don't have a event handler to work with the push notification!

When I unlock my device, these two methods are fired: 1. applicationWillEnterForeground 2. applicationDidBecomeActive

But in these two methods, I am not getting any push notification message information.

Comment: If my phone isn't locked, then I can read push notification in didReceiveRemoteNotification method, and if my application isn't running, get a push message and someone click on it, I can read push notification in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method.

Comment: Push notifications are not a lossless form of communication. There are other scenarios where users might miss messages. This is by design. Again: _you can't rely on the push notification being the only communication mechanism_.